# invalid type exception when changing account ownership only when assigning to a specific user record

Tags: apex

this error only happens when transferring ownership to a specific user record. error message says just this 3 words, no other stack trace appearing right after. the transfer of ownership is successful on other user records. the 2 user mentioned are both active, same role, profile, permissions, etc.

I enabled debug log to finest, but error is not captured via the debug logs.

Any idea how to debug further the root cause of this error?

[image]

Comment: Is this user an active user? Inactive users can't be assigned as owners of records.

Comment: yes. active user

Comment: Can you post the complete exception details?

Comment: that's basically it. no other error message after that. no debug logs saying exception neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround solved this by deleting all child contacts on the account record, transfer ownership, then restoring them via recycle bin.

debug logs still didn't capture the error message.